# Equivalent to NEW operator that uses mutators instead of construtor

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

JPQL queries can return custom result objects with the `NEW` operator:

```
  SELECT NEW myPackage.MyVO(e.fieldX, e.relationshipX.fieldY)
  FROM MyEntity AS e
```

This is very useful to feed VOs. The problem is, you have to create constructors that exactly match the number of arguments, order and types of your query projection. This starts to get messy when you use a lot of projections for the same VO... Either you have one big constructor in your VO and resort to a lot of `NULL` literals on your query, or your VO must have a lot of different constructors.

So my question is: Is there a way in JPQL to set result object fields through mutators instead of constructors?

To people with .NET background, I'm looking to a equivalent of [LINQ + object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473425.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1) certainly supports two ways of instantiating result objects *using no non-standard annotations or calls*, primarily driven by the fact that it also supports JDO and that has the requirement for it :-

1. Result type with argumented constructor (as you say)
2. Result type with default constructor, and with setters

Such as

```
TypedQuery<MyResultType> q = em.createQuery("SELECT x AS field1, y AS field2 FROM ...", MyResultType.class);
```

where MyResultType has setters "setField1", "setField2".

Comment: That's a very nice feature of DataNucleus, no non standard APIs and the behavior I need. I will surely try Datanucleus. Any chance of DataNucleus proposing this as a new feature for the Persistence API [(Current JSR)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/proposalDetails?id=338). Luckily we can have a standard for JPA 2.2 or JPA 3 :D.

Comment: I've no plans to request it, but you could easily enough. Just go to http://java.net/projects/jpa-spec  Simply raise an "issue" in their issue tracker and its then noted and can be tracked

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer **No** you can not use mutators in JPQL.

While I do not know `LINQ` I can not see this getting done without creating mess .

Now I am sure you know that Classes can have mutlple constructors . So why not create constructors where you will not have too feed in `null`.

Depending upon what you need and which JPA implementation you are using , most providers do provide non standard ways around it .e.g. Hibernate has `@formula` which in some cases be used instead to using a constructor.

I you are using JPA2 then criteria queries might be a better choice and can take care of these kind of things.

In somecases you might prefer using `@PostLoad` .

Either way you need to know this converstion in not happening in SQL so you are not really offloading any work to SQL . Which we generally prefer i.e. make SQL do as much work as possible in single hit.

Yes these are my generalizations and concrete solutions or requirements may not fit.